# Google Play OBB downloader library crashes on Android 8.0

Tags: android, google-play, android-8.0-oreo, background-service

OBB downloader library seems to use Context.startService(...) to download OBB in background, but on Android 8.0 this leads to crashes, if app itself is in the background.
This library registers a BroadcastReceiver:

```
mConnReceiver = new InnerBroadcastReceiver(this);
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
        ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
registerReceiver(mConnReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Receiver istelf:

```
private class InnerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final Service mService;

    InnerBroadcastReceiver(Service service) {
        mService = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        pollNetworkState();
        if (mStateChanged
                && !isServiceRunning()) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "InnerBroadcastReceiver Called");
            Intent fileIntent = new Intent(context, mService.getClass());
            fileIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT, mPendingIntent);
            // send a new intent to the service
            context.startService(fileIntent);
        }
    }
};
```

Crash stack stace:
[Downloader service crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnc7C.png)

So, what is the preferred way to avoid such crashes? Or this user experience is normal in Android 8.0+?